# Local notification not showing banner when app is in foreground

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I'm using react-native to write an iOS app and would like a local notification to appear in the foreground after triggering a UI action like a button tap. I'm using the 'react-native-push-notifications' library to set this up but notice that the alert banner does not show when my app is in the foreground. It does, however, work when the app is in the background. How can I do this, using react-native?